# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique and Undeclared identifier

Tags: solidity, truffle-contract, openzeppelin-contracts

I am trying to create a crowdsale contract using zeppelin. But i am facing following errors.

```
CrowdSale.sol:6:46: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
contract EdCoinCrowdSale is CappedCrowdSale, RefundableCrowdSale {
                                             ^-----------------^
CrowdSale.sol:24:51: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
    function setCrowdsaleStage(uint value) public onlyOwner {
                                                  ^-------^
```

I have imported contract using import.

`import "node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/RefundableCrowdSale.sol";`

I have looked at other solutions but i am still facing above mentioned errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, this was unfortunately just a typo.  I hope you found this quickly.
It is `RefundableCrowdsale` not `RefundableCrowdSale`

For information on using OpenZeppelin Crowdsales, please see the documentation:
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/crowdsales

If you have any questions on using OpenZeppelin you can always ask in the [community forum](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/)